# Data sent is uncompleted using asyncio.start_unix_server and a corutine

Tags: python, sockets, coroutine

I am writing some code to communicate two processes using the asyncio package (python 3.5 and in a Unix system).

I create an unix domain socket for that task, using the following code for the server process:

```
factory = asyncio.start_unix_server(listen, SOCKET_ADDR)
server = event_loop.run_until_complete(factory)
event_loop.run_forever()
```

where listen is a coroutine that receive the data and print its length:

```
async def listen(reader, writer):
    data_stream = await reader.read()
    writer.close()
    print(len(data_stream))
```

The client process just connects to that socket and sends a binary string:

```
# Coroutine that sends a binary string
async def send_data(socket_address):
    _, writer = await asyncio.open_unix_connection(socket_address)
    datastream = b'fooo'*18*1024
    print(len(datastream))
    writer.write(datastream)
    await writer.drain()
    writer.close()

# Connect to the socket and send the data
event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
event_loop.run_until_complete(send_data(SOCKET_ADDR))
```

I don't understand why the size of the datastream generated in the client is different from the data_stream received in the server. In fact, I always obtain the same results, so I suppose it is not stochastic. These are the different results I obtained:

```
datastream = b'fooo'*4*1024 --> Client-length 16384 // Server-length 16384 (Correct)
datastream = b'fooo'*5*1024 --> Client-length 20480 // Server-length 16384 (Uncompleted)
datastream = b'fooo'*18*1024 --> Client-length 73728 // Server-length 16384 (Uncompleted)
datastream = b'fooo'*19*1024 --> Client-length 77824 // Server-length 73728 (Uncompleted)
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Your write is stuck in a buffer in the client (`writer.transport._buffer`). I don't understand how it's supposed to be flushed. As a workaround, you can sleep after drain (e.g. `await asyncio.sleep(.1)`)

Comment: You were right! I tried to sleep and it worked. However, I wanted a more robust solution. Finally, what I did was to wait for an ack response from the server side, and this way it worked.

Comment: @jcozar87 have u figured out a more efficient solution for this? after 2 years plus